# POST php form using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, forms, send

I need any jQuery code to send form data without refreshing the page.

Method (POST): after submit form show "loading..." message or "loading image". If process.php = 1 (true) hide form and display ok message, and if process.php = 2 ( false ) not hide form and display any error message.

Answer (score 3):

```
var data = new Object();
data['formData'] = $('#form').serializeArray();    
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'process.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.result == 1) {
                $('#form').hide();
            } else {
                alert('error');
            }
        }
    });
```

process.php:

```
//...
echo json_encode(array('result' => 0)); // OR 1
```

Comment: Nice, Without json datatype method ? this not show ajax loading message.

Comment: @persipam, i didn't understand your comment) can u explain it?

Comment: in your code after submit not show any loading message or loading image. 2- for error jquery display alert box. please see my question. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to add form ID or any other identificator.

so, if your form is

```
<div id="message"> </div>
<form method="post" action="" id="myForm">
<input type="submit" name="send" id="sendData" />
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#sendData").click(function() {
  $("#message").html("loading ...");
  $.post("process.php", {
      submit: 1 //and any other POST data you separate with comma
  }, function(response) {
       if(response == 1) {
            $("#myForm").hide();
            $("#message").html("OK");
       } else {
            $("#message").html("error message");
       }
  });
});
});
```

now, after submit form you will get message "loading ..." while posting "process.php", then if process.php returns 1 the form will be hide and display OK else you get an error message.

Comment: nice. i tested this. thanks karo96. This worked with jquery 1.4.4 ?

Comment: Yes, probably, but use lastest version of jQuery (recommanded, not for $.post).

Comment: If i have text  filed with `id=email` in the form and i want to send to `process.php` , here in `process.php` how do i retrive the data and store it database and in jQuery code... how can we send at `line 5`